# What are the security risks for applications using Cordova's webview on mobile?

Tags: mobile

I'm creating hybrid apps in Cordova. It creates a webview and renders HTML/JS/CSS content inside it on mobile phones, making it look like an app, but really it's just a local web page.

Now I'm a bit concerned with security of these applications, specially on the sense of code injection, since, well, it's a web page so it seems to be vulnerable to cross scripting attacks.

Now my question is: does Cordova have mechanism (out of the box or native) to protect the app from this? How does the security of data inside a Cordova hybrid app compare to the security of data in a native app?